# Passing images between controllers in full resolution

Tags: swift

My problem is that that when I'm passing image from one controller to another somehow the image looks very bad (very low resolution). **The problem is not in passing images but that I'm requesting image in a wrong way.**

```
public var pickedImage: UIImage!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let asset = images[indexPath.row]
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()

    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize,
                                            contentMode: .aspectFit,
                                            options: nil) { (result, _) in
                                                self.pickedImage = result
        }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetailSegue" {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        dvc.vcImage = pickedImage
    }
}
```

Fun fact. When I'm displaying images in **collectionView** (in the same viewcontroller from which I'm trying to send) they're in full resolution even when I'm using same code as mentioned above.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photocell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoLibraryCollectionViewCell
    cell.image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.image.clipsToBounds = true
    let asset = images[indexPath.row]
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    if cell.tag != 0 {
            manager.cancelImageRequest(PHImageRequestID(cell.tag))
        }
    cell.tag = Int(manager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                        targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize,
                                            contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                            options: nil) { (result, _) in
                                                cell.image.image = result
        })
    return cell
}
```

Example: **Original**[image: Original image]
**With requestImage**
[image: Image with requestImage]

Comment: One of the things wrong with this code is that you’re using an asynchronous method but using it in a synchronous way. You request your image from the manager and then immediately call the segue. But the request is async so it will not have finished by the time you perform the segue. If you have asynchronous code you need to use it asynchronously. The best solution here would be to move your data model out of the collection view controller and use it as a global data storage. A small rework of the structure of the app.

Comment: @Fogmeister I don't think that what you said is the problem. Because I just tried to put UIImageView on the same controller and just requestImage and then show it on this UIImageView. And result is the same.

Comment: Can you show some screenshots of what you’re experiencing. It’s hard to tell what is happening with just your code. And what the problem is. Also, how do you know you’re getting a low res image? Can you log out the image size before and after the segue. Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister Added example in my question.

Comment: Cool. Which code goes with which image? Sorry, just confused as to what is happening? Can you explain it in steps. Which code runs and show which image? And then what do you do to get the next bit of code to run. And what is the next bit of code? And what does the image look like? Etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister Just posted working solution for me. I'm going to edit my question tomorrow and explain my code more understandable because still can't understand why it's not working even with the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution to my problem.

```
func convertImageFromAsset(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var image = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        image = result!
    })
    return image
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    pickedImage = convertImageFromAsset(asset: images[indexPath.item])
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetailSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend force unwrapping the result regardless but good solution nonetheless.